# data of records incorrect from table without PK

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am working with a data base I can't modify. There is a table that keeps track of changes in others tables and has no primary key.
I was able to replicate the Problem I am having in a test database. The sql server is MS-SQL 2008 R2.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrackerTest](
    [Action] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TrackComment] [varchar](254) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Dates are stores as integers with format yyyymmdd and time is the number of seconds since midnight.

and this is a fragment of a console application.

```
 var db = new DataTestEntities();
 var track = from t in db.TrackerTests select t;
 foreach (var test in track)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", test.Action, test.Date, test.Time, test.TrackComment);    
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
```

My problem is: 
if there are 2 records with the same date and time values, they both show the same Action and TrackComment values even though they are different in the database. 
For example:
with this data in the database:

```
insert into TrackerTest Values('action1',20141114,49231,'comment1');
insert into TrackerTest Values('action2',20141114,49231,'comment2');
insert into TrackerTest Values('action3',20141107,27028,'comment3');
insert into TrackerTest Values('action4',20141121,51633,'comment4');
insert into TrackerTest Values('action5',20141121,51633,'comment5');
```

I get this output in the console application

```
action1, 20141114, 49231, comment1
action1, 20141114, 49231, comment1
action3, 20141107, 27028, comment3
action4, 20141121, 51633, comment4
action4, 20141121, 51633, comment4
```

The number of records is fine but the content is not.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: can you profile the SQL that is actually executed?

Comment: I got the sql that is been executed and run it directly on the SQL Management studio and it works fine.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking around for a proper solution to this issue but no luck so far. 
As stated by @Chris Ballance  "**EF doesn't play well with non-PK tables.**"
I can not fix the model since the third party vendor does not allow me to do that, so I don't know if this could be considered a solution or a work around.
So, here is how I solved it. 
On another server we have, I created a connection to the first server using ["Linked Server"](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server). 
In that server there is a Data Base I created and my application use as well. I just  added a stored procedure that execute the query in the linked server. Call the stored procedure from EF and all the 
data is there just as it should be. 
Hopefully this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your looping code to use this instead:

```
foreach (var t in db.TrackerTests.ToList())
```

This will prevent lazy-loading of the enumeration you are looping over and might just fix your issue.

However, if you're working with a table that doesn't have a primary key, you're not really working with a table, just a graph of data without a well-defined way to enumerate or follow an index.

**Fix your model instead of band-aiding the problem**  If you can't change the db, find whoever can and find out why primary keys are not defined on this table.

Comment: Thanks Christ for the fast answer but I just tested it and I am still getting the same output.

Comment: EF doesn't play well with non-PK tables.  Can you make a copy of the table, add a PK, then try the same code?  That would give you what you need to take it to your DBA and say, "Hey Buddy, this is broken, fix your stuff & here's why."

Comment: When you look at the table directly (assuming you can do this) are the inserts happening as you expect or are you perhaps getting duplicated data at insert time instead of at read time?

Comment: I add the primary key and it works fine. I always suspected the problem is with the pk. Anyways, there is no way I can modify the table, it is from a third party and I just can read from it. On top of that that table already has millions of records. Regarding your second comment, I have access to the db, inserts are happening automatically from the 3rd party software and they look ok. There is another column in the table that contains a time stamp of the transaction. It is save as a varchar but it shows a difference in milliseconds between inserts.

Comment: Sounds like the timestamp is being used as a unique identifier.  I wonder if something is dropping precision and inserts within milliseconds of each other are being treated as the same row sometimes in your reads.

Comment: Can you add and point EF to an intermediary table with a proper PK that's just a pull from the 3rd party table?

Comment: Add a view with a unique identifier and query that?

Comment: @Pleun Thanks for the suggestion, but I can modify the database.

Comment: In that case you better revert to ADO.NET or db.executequery

Comment: Agree with Pleun, EF is not going to play well with this DB.  If you can't modify the db, revert to ADO.NET or db.ExecuteQuery